# Error when importing an image using Micasense library: Invalid version '6.0.0-USBE'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm working on a project that involves image processing using the Micasense library in Python. I've successfully imported all the required libraries, including OpenCV, ExifTool, and PyZbar. However, when I try to import an image and perform some operations on it, I encounter an error related to the version.

Here's the code snippet that triggers the error:

```
from micasense.image import Image
imagePath = r'C:\Micasense\imageprocessing\ExerciseMaterials\IMG_0000_1.tif'

img = Image(imagePath)
img.plot_raw(figsize=(8.73,8.73));
```

And here's the error message I'm getting:

```
InvalidVersion                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_35832\2288500639.py in <module>
      3 imagePath = r'C:\Micasense\imageprocessing\ExerciseMaterials\IMG_0000_1.tif'
      4 
----> 5 img = Image(imagePath)
      6 img.plot_raw(figsize=(8.73,8.73));
      7 

C:\Micasense\imageprocessing\micasense\image.py in __init__(self, image_path, exiftool_obj)
    128                 self.direct_to_diffuse_ratio = self.meta.direct_irradiance() / self.meta.scattered_irradiance()
    129                 self.estimated_direct_vector = self.meta.estimated_direct_vector()
--> 130                 if self.meta.horizontal_irradiance_valid():
    131                     self.horizontal_irradiance = self.meta.horizontal_irradiance()
    132                 else:

C:\Micasense\imageprocessing\micasense\metadata.py in horizontal_irradiance_valid(self)
    300         else:
    301             raise ValueError("Camera model is required to be RedEdge or Altum, not {} ".format(self.camera_model()))
--> 302         return version.parse(version_string) >= version.parse(good_version)
    303 
    304     def spectral_irradiance(self):

~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\micasense\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py in parse(version)
     50     :raises InvalidVersion: When the version string is not a valid version.
     51     """
---> 52     return Version(version)
     53 
     54 

~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\micasense\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py in __init__(self, version)
    196         match = self._regex.search(version)
    197         if not match:
--> 198             raise InvalidVersion(f"Invalid version: '{version}'")
    199 
    200         # Store the parsed out pieces of the version

InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '6.0.0-USBE'
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with the Micasense library? What could be causing this "Invalid version" error, and how can I fix it?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

actually the code u see is a test Installation, but the issue is same, so I just post a simplest code.
I'm newbie about this stuff, so please I dont have idea how to resolve this issue. I've checked the documentation and made sure that I'm using the correct versions of the libraries. I'm using Python 3.9, jupyter notebook,exiftools, and the Micasense library version 0.1.4.

Comment: Looks like the version stored in the tif's metadata is in a format that is not compatible with pythons packaging version format. Youo could try to put `return True` in the first line of the function `horizontal_irradiance_valid` `C:\Micasense\imageprocessing\micasense\metadata.py`. Also check if you have a file called `metadata.pyc` in `C:\Micasense\imageprocessing\micasense\pycache`